# How to construct datafeed.js for TradingView Charts for react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tradingview-api, f2-chart

I am already using F2Charts, want to switch to TradingView Charts. In F2Chart I provide all the rendered graphdata through chart.source where I know in which way an array has to be constructed to properly display the result, but in TradingView Charts I could not figure out how to pass the data through the datafeed. Can anyone help ?

```
import DATAFEED from './datafeed';

function initOnReady(symbol, interval, data) {
     var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
        // debug: true, // uncomment this line to see Library errors and warnings in the

        fullscreen: true,
        symbol: symbol,
        interval: interval,
        container_id: "tv_chart_container",

        //  BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL

        datafeed: DATAFEED, // ---> here I have array how to construct it compatible to tradingview
        library_path: "charting_library/",
        locale: getParameterByName('lang') || "en",

        disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"],

        enabled_features: ["study_templates"],
        charts_storage_url: 'https://saveload.tradingview.com',
        charts_storage_url: 'http://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}',
        charts_storage_api_version: "1.1",
        client_id: 'tradingview.com',
        user_id: 'public_user_id',
    });

};
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-tutorial/blob/master/documentation/datafeed-implementation.md) - Datafeed is an Object you supply to the TradingView Widget. It has a set of methods like getBars or resolveSymbol that are called by the Charting Library in certain cases. The datafeed returns results using callback functions.